# Erlang and mysql

Tags: mysql, erlang

I have a users table in mysql with **userid**, **username**, **password** etc
Using **mysql-otp** i query like

```
select * from users where username = ?
```

Its returns **ColumnNames** and **Rows**.
**Rows** are like

```
[[38, <<"joe">>, <<"passwordhash">>..]]
```

Suppose i have a hash to compare

```
Hash = "passhash".
```

As its my 3rd day coding in erlang, what i am currently doing/testing is

```
[[_, _, UserPass, _,..]] = Rows.
```

Which stores password in **UserPass**.

```
Pass = binary_to_list(UserPass).
```

Which i can then compare like

```
Hash == Pass.
```

Is this approach correct or i am doing it all wrong?
There must be a proper way of getting data out of what is supposedly list inside a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There must be a proper way of getting data out of what is supposedly
>   list inside a list

The proper way to get at your target data is to use pattern matching to *deconstruct* whatever type of collection contains your data. Because `mysql-otp` returns a list of rows matching the query, where each row itself is a list, the data is in the form of a list of lists.  Therefore, in order to match a list of lists your pattern also has to be a list of lists.

> As its my 3rd day coding in erlang, what i am currently doing/testing
>   is
>
> ```
> [[_, _, UserPass, _,..]] = Rows.
> ```

Bravo.

If you know `mysql-otp` will only return one row, or you are only interested in the first row, you could simplify the pattern like this:

```
[_, _, UserPass, _, ...] = hd(Rows).
```

`hd` is shorthand for head, i.e. the head of the list.  Or, you could accomplish the same thing by hand like this:

```
[FirstRow | _Tail] = Rows,
[_, _, UserPass, _, ...] = FirstRow.
```

=======

Another way to extract the password:

```
UserPass = lists:nth(3, hd(Rows)).
```

Comment: As username is unique, it should only return 1 row.

Comment: @user10844401, What did you not understand about the following sentence: *The **proper way** to get at your target data is to use **pattern matching** to deconstruct whatever type of collection contains your data.*  But, if for some inexplicable reason you find pattern matching abhorrent,  I posted yet another way to get at your data--see the bottom of my answer.